# OpenCV opens camera at the first load, but if I refresh the page, it doesn't bring camera (can't open camera by index)

Tags: python, django, video-streaming, ubuntu-20.04

I have this Django project for Video-Streaming. So everything works perfectly fine on my system (**MacOS**).
But here's what happens in **Ubuntu 20.04**:

- Works fine for the first loading
- If I refresh the page or go to other pages and come back again, the camera is not being opened by my app. This is the error:

`[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-ms668fyv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index`

This is **Views.py**

```
import cv2
from django.http import HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
import threading


class VideoStream(View):
    def __init__(self):
        cv2.destroyallwindows()
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L2)

    def __del__(self):
        self.camera.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.camera.read()
        if ret:
            _, jpeg = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
            return jpeg.tobytes()
        else:
            # print('frame',frame)
            return None

    def generate(self):
        while True:
            frame = self.get_frame()
            if frame is not None:
                yield (
                    b"--frame\r\n"
                    b"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + frame + b"\r\n\r\n"
                )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return StreamingHttpResponse(
            self.generate(), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame"
        )

class StreamView(View):
    template_name = "stream.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

This is **video-stream.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Real-Time Video Stream</h1>
    <p>This is Paragraph</p>
    <img id="video-frame" src="" alt="Video Stream" />

    <script>
      function updateFrame() {
        console.log("in update frame");
          $('#video-frame').attr('src', '{% url 'video_stream' %}' + '?' + Date.now());
          // setTimeout(updateFrame, 100);  // Refresh every 100 milliseconds
      }
      updateFrame();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is **url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("video-stream/", VideoStream.as_view(), name="video-stream"),
    path("stream/", StreamView.as_view(), name="stream"),
]
```

Thanks in advance :)